# Changing numbers found in a string to 1's

Tags: excel

If I am given a string (in Excel 2013 and I don't want to use VBA):

> 0203534420

Can Excel replace/substitute the cells that do not contain "0" and turn them into "1"?

Then the string would result in:

> 0101111110

Then from the above code, can Excel use this code as a way to determine which header to print from a column above?

Starting from left to right if I had a header that would be printed only if the value in that corresponding column was not zero[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but this question might be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(--MID(E4,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(E4))),1) >0,CHAR(64+ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(E4)))),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

TEXTJOIN is only available with a subscription to Office 365 Excel.

[image]

---

In 2013 you will need to parse each character separately:

```
=IF(--MID(E3,1,1)>0,"A","") & IF(--MID(E3,2,1)>0,"B","")  & IF(--MID(E3,3,1)>0,"C","")  & IF(--MID(E3,4,1)>0,"D","")  & IF(--MID(E3,5,1)>0,"E","")  & IF(--MID(E3,6,1)>0,"F","")  & IF(--MID(E3,7,1)>0,"G","")  & IF(--MID(E3,8,1)>0,"H","")  & IF(--MID(E3,9,1)>0,"I","")  & IF(--MID(E3,10,1)>0,"J","")
```

[image]

Comment: If you wanted to use the headers as per the image in the question just change the letter references in Scott's answer from `"A"` to `$A$1`, `"B"` to `$B$1` and so on.  Hard coding it the way Scott has does have the advantage of freeing up your row for other uses.  using the cell reference is good if you ever want to mix up the coding without adjusting the formulas

Comment: good thing there were only 10 digits.  you might start to run out of character you can type in the formula!